# Ubuntu VM ssh terminal breakage

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, vpn

I have ubuntu installed on a VBox VM on an OSX host.  SSH to machines via VPN worked fine for months.  All of a sudden, I can ssh, but whenever I do anything that scrolls the output, the terminal hangs.

edit -- when I vpn and ssh from a  terminal on my mac, I get no errors.

Any insights into how this can happen?

Comment: So local connections work, but remote connections do not?

Comment: @ricbax, no.  VPN + SSH on the host works.  VPN + SSH on the guest OS does not because terminal freezes.  Had been working for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing changed on the box I would would suspicious of any changes on the machine you are using to remote in.